# asp.net Dynamic Column Gridview selectedindexchanged not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has dynamic columns generated.

I used AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" property and tried  testing with a label on selectedindexchanged

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Test";
}
```

It worked with a gridview which uses sqldatasource but doesn't work on this gridview. This is my code that generates the columns and rows

```
private void BindGrid(List<string> SelectedInfo)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < SelectedInfo.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(SelectedInfo[i], typeof(string)));
    }

    List<string[]> InfoList = getInfoList(SelectedInfo);

    for (int i = 0; i < InfoList.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(InfoList[i]);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: The code works just fine. Please make sure you have called  BindGrid(SelectedInfo); at the correct place or at Page_Load